# My parent bitmap doesnt contains inner bitmaps design drawn by canvas in android

Tags: android, kotlin, canvas, bitmap

My scenario is iam designing design for print using canvas and my customview to load that canvas.In my case i have created multiple inner canvas  inside  parent canvas so iam created parentcanvas from activity and attached with one parentbitmap and  designed each inner canvas as section by section with startpositon ,at the end i can able see my design on ui but while converting my customview as bitmap and saving in sd storage its doesnt have my design,its showing white as empty while debugging find only my inner created canvas and bitmap  images have design but my parent bitmap doesnt contain design.so How Can i get whole design on parent bitmap.

PrintToolActivity:

setContentView(R.layout.activity_printtool)
customView = findViewById(R.id.customPrintView)
customView.setPrintDetails(mappedPrintProfileDetail, mappedPrintFieldDetail, printModel, null)
val tempBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(customView.canvasWidth.toInt(), customView.canvasHeight.toInt(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
val parentCanvas = Canvas(tempBitmap)
parentCanvas.drawBitmap(tempBitmap, 0f, 0f, null)
customView.parentBitmap = tempBitmap
customView.init(null)
customView.invalidate()

```
 customView.draw(parentCanvas)                                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                          
                                                                                                         
 customView.saveImage(tempBitmap, customView.bitmapPath)
```

HeaderSection.kt:

```
 val headerBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap((printProfileDetail.headerWidth * mmToPixelConvertorValue).toInt(),bitmapHeight.toInt(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
    val headerCanvas = Canvas(headerBitmap)
    headerCanvas.drawColor(-1)
   canvas.drawBitmap(headerBitmap, ((canvasWidth/2) - (printProfileDetail.headerWidth * mmToPixelConvertorValue)/2).toFloat() ,0f, paint)
   headerCanvas.drawText(headerSegment.colName, (headerSegment.xPosition * mmToPixelConvertorValue).toFloat(), (headerSegment.yPosition * mmToPixelConvertorValue).toFloat(), paint)
```

DetailSection.Kt:

```
        detailBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap((printProfileDetail.paperWidth * mmToPixelConvertorValue).toInt(), parentBitmapHeight.toInt(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
        detailCanvas = Canvas(detailBitmap)
        detailCanvas.drawColor(-1)
         canvas.drawBitmap(detailBitmap, ((canvasWidth/2) - (printProfileDetail.paperWidth * mmToPixelConvertorValue)/2).toFloat(),canvasTop, paint)
                            detailCanvas.drawText(colName, (detailSegment.xPosition  * mmToPixelConvertorValue).toFloat() , totalYposition.toFloat(), paint)

  CustomView.kt:       
//Ondraw method
 override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas)
        canvas.drawColor(-1);
       paint.style = Paint.Style.STROKE;
        paint.strokeWidth = 2f;
        paint.isAntiAlias = true
    Controller(canvas,paint,this,parentBitmap).segmentSeparator(printProfileDetail,printFieldDetail,printModel)
        }
```

Comment: Please be more clear on what you are asking, the problem description is almost impossible to read and understand.

Comment: Edited my question for your better understanding,actually iam creating multiple individual canvas inside parent canvas but while saving image my parent canvas doesnt have design,only inner canvas has design.Can u please help me on this.No solutions helping me till now